# How to iterate Json object in shell script

Tags: json, shell, sh

I am writing a shell script to run some api's. It return response fine but i need some specific parameter to grep from the response and want to save in file.
My script look like

```
#!/bin/sh
response=$(curl 'https://example.com' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' )
echo "$response"
```

reponse is something like

```
{
status:"success",
response:{
   "target":"",
   "content":"test content"
}
}
```

Response is fine and i am able to write whole response in file but My requirement is to save only "content" inside "response" object using the script. which i need for another api.
**Note:** I cannot change api responses as I am working third party api's;

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the output is proper JSON:

```
$ cat proper.json
{
  "status": "success",
  "response": {
    "target": "",
    "content": "test content"
  }
}
$ response=$(cat proper.json)
```

You could use `jq`:

```
$ echo $response | jq -r '.response.content'
test content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the value of contents into a variable (`$content`).

`content=$(echo "$response" | cut -d'"' -f 7)`

Explanation - Split the `$response` using `"` (double quote) as the delimiter and use the 7th field of the output (i.e the value (`test content`) of `content` in the json response)

Here is an excerpt from the description and usage of the `cut` command

> if you like to extract a whole field, you can combine option -f and -d. The option -f specifies which field you want to extract, and the option -d specifies what is the field delimiter that is used in the input file.

Comment: Thanks for response, problem fixed by grep "\"content\":" | awk -F":" '{ print $2}'

Answer (score 0):

You can `grep` for the `content` and then use awk to split by `:` and take only the value, not the key

```
grep "\"content\":" | awk -F":" '{ print $2}'
```

Will print `"test content"`

Comment: thanks @Robert D.Magos
It worked :)